# Switch to turn audio on and off is not working as expected electron desktop capturer

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to implement a switch to turn audio on and off with electron desktop capturer and my code actually does work as soon as I launch my app but it can only record once when I tried to record second time and save the video it again saves the video which it recorded for the first time and however many times I record it saves the video which I first recorded someone please help with this I hope am clear with my problem

JavaScript file

```
const { writeFile } = require('original-fs');
const { dialog , Menu } = remote;

const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');


let mediarecorderwithaudio;
let mediarecorderwithoutaudio;
const recordedChunks = [];

var checkaudio;

playvideo();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      checkaudio = true;
      // do this
      console.log('Checked');
    } else {
      // do that
      checkaudio = false;
      console.log('Not checked');
    }
  });
});

var recordingtxt = document.getElementById('recordtext');




const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');

stopBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';

stopBtn.onclick = e => {
  if(checkaudio == true){
    mediarecorderwithaudio.stop();
  }else{
    mediarecorderwithoutaudio.stop();
  }
  startBtn.classList.remove('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Start Recording';
  startBtn.className = 'buttonStart'
  stopBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  recordingtxt.innerText = "Now Previewing => " + source.name;
};

//Adding changes
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
startBtn.onclick = e => {

  if(checkaudio == true){
    mediarecorderwithaudio.start();
  }else{
    mediarecorderwithoutaudio.start();
  }
  
  startBtn.classList.add('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Recording';
  stopBtn.style.visibility = 'visible'
  startBtn.className = 'buttonRecording'
  recordingtxt.innerText = "Now Recording => " + source.name;
};

const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;

async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  });

  if(checkaudio == true){
    const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
      inputSources.map(source => {
        return {
          label: source.name,
          click: () => selectSourceWithAudio(source)
        };
      })
    );

    videoOptionsMenu.popup();
  
  }else{
    const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
      inputSources.map(source => {
        return {
          label: source.name,
          click: () => selectSourceWithoutAudio(source)
        };
      })
    );

    videoOptionsMenu.popup();
  
  }

  
  
  
}


async function playvideo(){

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: 'screen:0:0',
      }
    },

      video:{
          mandatory:{
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: 'screen:0:0',
             
          }
      }
  }

  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints);

  videoElement.srcObject = stream;

  videoElement.play();
}


async function selectSourceWithAudio(source){

    videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

    recordingtxt.innerText = "Now Previewing => " + source.name;
    
    const constraints = {
      audio: {
          mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
        }
      },
  
      video:{
            mandatory:{
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,

            }
          }
    }
  
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia(constraints);
  
      videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  
      videoElement.muted = true;
  
      videoElement.play();
  
      console.log(source.id);

      const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'};
      mediarecorderwithaudio = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

      mediarecorderwithaudio.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
      mediarecorderwithaudio.onstop = handleStop;

}

async function selectSourceWithoutAudio(source){

  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  recordingtxt.innerText = "Now Previewing => " + source.name;
  
  const constraints = {
    audio: false,

    video:{
          mandatory:{
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,

            }
        }
  }

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints);

    videoElement.srcObject = stream;

    videoElement.muted = true;

    videoElement.play();

    console.log(source.id);

    const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'};
    mediarecorderwithoutaudio = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

    mediarecorderwithoutaudio.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mediarecorderwithoutaudio.onstop = handleStop;

}

  

    
    



function handleDataAvailable(e){
    console.log('video data available')
    recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}


async function handleStop(e){
    const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
        type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
    });

    const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

    const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
        buttonLabel: 'Save Video',
        defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`
    });

    console.log(filePath);

    writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log('Video saved successfully')); 
}
```

And here's the HTML File

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Margs Screen Recorder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script defer src="render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div style="position: relative; align-items: center; text-align: center;">
      <h1>Margs Screen Recorder</h1>
    </div>
    

    <div style="position: relative; align-content: center;">

      <video width="896" height="504" style="position: relative;"></video>
    
    </div>
    

    <div style="position: relative; ">
      <button id="startBtn" class="buttonStart">Start Recording</button>
      <button id="stopBtn" class="buttonStop">Stop Recording</button>
    </div>

    <h5 id="recordtext">Now Previewing => Entire Screen</h5>
    



    <hr />

    <button id="videoSelectBtn" class="button is-text">
      Choose what to record
    </button>

    <div id="button-container" style="position: relative; top: 25px;">
      <b1>Audio</b1>
      <label class="switch" style="position: relative; left: 15px;">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
   

  </body>
</html>
```